# Combining two Python lists in an interleaved manner

Tags: python, list, python-2.x

I want to interleave two lists. For example:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
arr2 = [9,8,7,6]
```

I't like to get an output like

```
[1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5,6]
```

I have created the following script, but it's not working for some reason:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
arr2 = [9,8,7,6]
x = 0

for a in arr2:
    x = x + 2
    arr1.insert(x, a)
```

Where am I going wrong? I am not looking for random shuffling. I am using python2.x

Comment: Those are `set` not arrays

Comment: "Can I get an output like {1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5,6}" -- you cannot get a set with duplicate elements, perhaps you meant a `list`?

Comment: and a set has no concept of order... so you can't.... Do you need a set or do you want a list?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question. @user3100115

Comment: @BrianCain I have changed my question, Forgive me but I am new to this.

Comment: @Ben no I don't want to shuffle them randomly. I need to shuffle them in an order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a different way to do this, without imports.

```
mylist = []
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [9,8,7,6]
for x in range(max(len(a), len(b))):
    if x < len(a):
        mylist.append(a[x])
    if x < len(b):
        mylist.append(b[x])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip_longest` and `chain.from_iterable` from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module:

```
>>> arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> arr2 = [9,8,7,6]
>>> from itertools import chain, zip_longest
>>> [i for i in chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(arr1, arr2)) if i is not None]
[1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5, 6]
```

You need to use `izip_longest` instead of `zip_longest` in python-2.x

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to deal with sentinel values and ever wish to deal with an arbitrary amount of iterables as input, then you want to grab and use the `roundrobin` recipe from https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 0):

if you actually want to shuffle them in a randomized fashion the key would be to combine them into one list and use shuffle().

```
from random import shuffle
import itertools as it

arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
arr2 = [9,8,7,6]
x = list(it.chain(arr1,arr2))
shuffle(x)
print(x)
```

**EDIT** question was updated to reflect the order desired wasn't random.

Comment: I was about to post a simple `lst3 = arr1+arr2; random.shuffle(lst3)`, but the whole thing evolved in a weird way... :D